# Proof that a matrix function can be made arbitrarily close to identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, normed-spaces

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
Define the following matrix function:

$$ \phi(A) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{A^i}{(i+1)!} $$

for any $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. A useful identity is $e^A = I + A \phi(A)$. I want to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\norm{\phi(A \delta) - I} < \epsilon$$

for any matrix norm $\norm{\cdot}$.

**My Proof.** Plugging the definitions

$$\begin{align*}
 \norm{\phi(A \delta) - I} &= \norm{I + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^i \delta^i}{(i+1)!} - I} \\
 &= \delta \norm{A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}}
\end{align*}$$

Since $\phi(A \delta)$ converges there exists a $N < \infty$ such that

$$\norm{A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}} < N$$

So, selecting $\delta = \epsilon / N$ gives the desired result.  QED

The result is obviously true but I think some rigour is missing. It is obvious that $\phi(A)$ is convergent for any $A$, since $e^A$ is also convergent. I think the point that disturbs me is the part "there exist a $N$" while there is a $\delta$ inside the norm and $\delta$ is selected according to $N$.

Is the thing that disturb me a problem? Is there a better way to prove this?

**Edited Proof.** Assume that $\delta < 1$ and plug into the definitions to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
 \norm{\phi(A \delta) - I} &= \norm{I + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^i \delta^i}{(i+1)!} - I} \\
 &= \delta \norm{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}} \\
 &\leq \delta \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A^{i}} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!} \\
 &\leq \delta \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A}^{i} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!} \\
 &< \delta \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A}^{i}} {(i+1)!} \\
 &= \delta [\phi(\norm{A})-1]
\end{align*}$$

Selecting $\delta = \min\{1,\epsilon/[\phi(\norm{A})-1]\}$ gives the desired result.  QED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can *directly* prove that the sum converges by using the properties of a matrix norm as follows:$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}$
$$
\norm{A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}} \leq 
\norm A \norm{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}} \leq 
\norm A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \norm{\frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}} = \\
\norm A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A^{i-1}} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!} \leq 
\norm A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A}^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}
$$
If we assume $\delta<1$, we can add
$$
\norm A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A}^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!} \leq
\norm A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\norm{A}^{i-1} 1^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}
$$
I don't know about assuming that $\phi(A)$ "obviously" converges, but this method certainly works.

Comment: I said $\phi(A)$ obviously converges because of the identity $e^A = I + A \phi(A)$ and it is well-known that $e^A$ converges for all $A$. What about after that part? Can we say there exists a finite $N$ such that $\| A \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{A^{i-1} \delta^{i-1}} {(i+1)!}\| < N$, so we can select $\delta = \epsilon / N$, while there is $\delta$ term inside the norm?

Comment: Argue that the series is increasing over $\delta$ and plug in $\delta=1$ to be an upper bound. I'll edit that in.

Comment: I've edited my proof. I think it's OK now.

Comment: Very good! It's perfectly fine now.